# Link GitHub project to Code Review

Tags: discussion, feature-request, third-party

I am currently writing some open source that's available in [GitHub](https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsSQL). Of course I am also getting the [code reviewed here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/94901/507).

One of the things with GitHub is the documentation allows me to put little tags in the documentation that get evaluated (see [README.md](https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsSQL/blob/master/README.md))

An example is the travis build (a tool for building and running unit tests automatically).

Example:

```
[![Build Status](https://travis-ci.org/Loki-Astari/ThorsSQL.svg?branch=master)](https://travis-ci.org/Loki-Astari/ThorsSQL)
```

Resulting in: [image: Build Status]

What would be nice if there is an equivalent API for Code Review. So I could add a snippet like the above to my GitHub documentation that shows a summary of being reviewed on Code Review:

Now I am not an artist (so please don't use this):

[image: Loki's Example]

Might even become a thing :-)

#### Added:

Can we also incorporate the Code Review icon when we officially get out of Beta.

Also be good if we could get the image of the accepted reviewer into item? [image]

Comment: Did you really create `ThorsSQL.svg` ... hehehe?

Comment: That would be great.

Comment: I can dig it, but what does the 14 represent in your example?

Comment: @RubberDuck: I don't know. That would be something we need to discuss. What do you put on the right and left?

Comment: And how to handle [certain repositories](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck) that has `i++` questions?

Comment: Actually it is quite simple to create [shields](http://shields.io/), there is a webservice for it. Example for number of reviewed snippets: https://img.shields.io/badge/reviewed-14-green.svg

Comment: @Pyfisch: That's very useful. But I was hoping to generate something that was dynamic based on the status of the git-hub review.

Comment: @LokiAstari: actually you can propose new services at [their Github repo](https://github.com/badges/shields). There are already many [requests](https://github.com/badges/shields/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue) to add new services.

Comment: @Pyfisch Thank you for that link, that will essentially make it possible to create our own dynamically generated shields. Now the question is primarily about what we want to show in the shields.

Comment: @Pyfisch: Thanks. Its truly amazing what is available on the web if you only know it exists.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg: There is already one for [stackexchange. https://github.com/badges/shields/pull/387] so our request is not unique (which is good). The bad part was that it was submitted **May-9**. Maybe it has not been integrated because they have not fixed the review comments.

Comment: @LokiAstari That request seems to be about user reputation, badges and tags though, not about specific questions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Update

Implemented, see [the Code Review question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/95459/shielding-your-codereview-on-github), for feature requests please [open an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/Zomis/CodeReview-Shield/issues)

It looks a little something like this:

[Code Review http://www.zomis.net/codereview/shield/?qid=95459&mode=score](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/95459/31562) [Code Review http://www.zomis.net/codereview/shield/?qid=95459&mode=answers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/95459/31562) [Code Review http://www.zomis.net/codereview/shield/?qid=95459&mode=views](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/95459/31562)

To create a Code Review Shield easily, use the [Code Review Shield Creator](http://www.zomis.net/codereview/shield/create.html)

---

I love this idea, and I love the fact that this is something we can implement ourselves, without requiring Stack Exchange. So I think someone of us should make it (is quite possible that someone will be me within a few days, unless someone else is faster).

About what to show, this is an example of what is retrieved from the Stack Exchange API [when querying a question](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=79408&filter=default&site=codereview&run=true):

```
  "tags": [
    "java",
    "stackexchange",
    "spring"
  ],
  "owner": {
    "reputation": 35519,
    "user_id": 31562,
    "user_type": "registered",
    "accept_rate": 81,
    "profile_image": "https://i.stack.imgur.com/cV8hf.jpg?s=128&g=1",
    "display_name": "Simon Andr&#233; Forsberg",
    "link": "https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/31562/simon-andr%c3%a9-forsberg"
  },
  "is_answered": true,
  "view_count": 1718,
  "answer_count": 2,
  "score": 34,
  "last_activity_date": 1428533615,
  "creation_date": 1422921671,
  "last_edit_date": 1428533615,
  "question_id": 79408,
  "link": "https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/79408/you-are-being-watched-comments-of-interest",
  "title": "You are being watched! - Comments of Interest"
```

Some of the most interesting things we can choose from there IMO are:

- is_answered: Might be something to show for questions that are still unanswered? (Can be used to determine the color, red for unanswered and green for answered?)
- answer_count: Probably not what you want to show off, especially not for questions that have few answers.
- view_count: That might be something you want to share, at least if it has a reasonable amount of views.
- score: Is definitely something that can be used!

Note that it is also possible to retrieve [the answers to a question](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-on-questions#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=79408&filter=default&site=codereview&run=true) but I don't find that info very interesting for this feature.

Comment: To me. The actual score is not that important. But "view_count" is a measure that people have at least looked at it. If there is an accepted answer should be included in some way. Maybe "answer_count".

Comment: While there is not an accepted answer we could go with one metric. Like: **Being-Reviewed:  <Answer Count>**. When an answer is accepted it goes to **Reviewed: <View Count>**.

Comment: @LokiAstari If I will be the one to implement it, I will probably make it an option :)

Comment: I am the last person you should ask about designing something visual (back end C++ remember). I am just throwing out ideas (see if any resonate with meta users).