# How do I properly give attribution to code found on Code Review?

Tags: support, licensing

If I have a project that I uploaded to GitHub and I bring one of the classes to Code Review, how should I go about giving attribution to any improvements I decide to use in my code on GitHub?

The [Attribution Required](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) blogpost linked on the bottom of any Code Review page mentions the following requirements:

> 1. **Visually indicate that the content is from Stack Overflow or the Stack Exchange network** in some way. It doesn't have to be obnoxious; a
>      discreet text blurb is fine.
> 2. **Hyperlink directly to the original question** on the source site (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345)
> 3. **Show the author names** for every question and answer
> 4. **Hyperlink each author name** directly back to their user profile page on the source site (e.g.,
>      https://stackoverflow.com/users/12345/username)

---

If I take part of [one of my questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/126071/74727) as an example, one of my methods was improved in the following way:

**Before**

```
private static boolean isSolution(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f, int g, int h) {
    if (a + b - 9 != 4)
        return false;
    if ((c - d) * e != 4)
        return false;
    if (f + g - h != 4)
        return false;
    if ((a + c) / f != 4)
        return false;
    if ((b - d) * g != 4)
        return false;
    if (9 - e - h != 4)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

**After**

```
private boolean isSolved(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f, int g, int h) {
    return (a + b - 9 == 4) && ((c - d) * e == 4) && (f + g - h == 4) && ((a + c) == 4 * f) && ((b - d) * g == 4)
            && (9 - e - h == 4);
}
```

**Is it OK to not give any attribution within the source code?** Seeing as the official explanation by Jeff Atwood says it needs to be indicated "in some way", can all attributions be tucked away in a separate file with little or no mention of it in the source?

To demonstrate what I am suggesting, take the following as an example. The javadoc at the head of the class incorporating the change looks like as follows:

```
/**
 * This class does a.
 *
 * @author Amani Kilumanga
 */
```

The head of the file looks like the following:

```
/** 
 * 
 * Copyright (C) 2016 Amani Kilumanga
 *
 * This software may be modified and distributed under the terms
 * of the CC BY-SA 3.0 license.  See the LICENSE file for details.
 */
```

The attributions are then all listed in a separate file (ATTRIBUTIONS.txt), placed in the root directory of the project:

> Modifications were made based on the following Stack Exchange network content:
>
> "Question Title" (Question URL), by "Question Author" (User profile
>   URL)
>
> Answer (Answer URL), by "Answer Author" (User profile URL)
>
> Answer (Answer URL), by "Answer Author" (User profile URL)
>
> Answer (Answer URL), by "Answer Author" (User profile URL)

Answer (score 3):

The blog you link is from 2009, seven years ago. There are plenty of [discussions on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=attribution%20is%3aquestion) and lengthy words in the [Stack Exchange Network Terms of Service](http://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service) and [Content Policy](http://stackexchange.com/legal/content-policy). But your question is more a question of *should do* not *required to do*.

Something that you can do, [that I've done](https://github.com/RaymondWise/Excel-Workday-Report-Parser), is use a [widget](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5522/link-github-project-to-code-review) to link to code review reviews in the `README`, where licensing is usually located.

Something else that I do, in a project I contribute to, is [indicate the author in the code](https://github.com/byronwall/bUTL/blob/master/src/code/Formatting_Helpers.bas). It's a bit sloppy, but it works, especially for something hosted on github.

Given that questions or answers may be deleted from codereivew *and* given that identity or users on SE is not verified, I think linking to questions, like how you've indicated, is fine. Maybe they go down, but the licensing on SE covers that once it's posted, it's fair play no matter what happens going forward.

If you prefer to go further with attribution - that's awesome, go for it. I haven't specifically referenced [Mathieu](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/users/23788/mats-mug) or [Zak](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/users/81541/kaz) (or others) in my open source projects on github, where I've used their input specifically for parts of [my?] code, but given the nature of open source and codereview, I don't think they mind.

However, if I were to [take an entire class of Zak's](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/128578/logical-predicate-class), I think both he and I would prefer I say so at the top of the class.

Basically - do what you feel comfortable doing, most likely, do what you'd want others to do for you.

Comment: The github project you linked to is MIT, but you liked to Code Review content... I'm not clear if you *used* CR content in your MIT project, or if you only linked to it. I thought CR content was incompatible with MIT.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the widget thing I created, I was about to mention that :)

Comment: @AmaniKilumanga See [Which licenses are compatible with Code Review?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/3830/31562)

Comment: @SimonForsberg yeah, MIT → CC is legal, but CC → MIT is not, unless all the copyright holders of the CC content dual-license to something compatible with MIT. So just using a widget is not enough to use CC content in an MIT project. Hence my above comment.

Comment: @AmaniKilumanga my code is MIT, always. If it's on CR, then it's CC on CR and still MIT on mine.

Comment: OK, but did you use code review contributions in your code; the code with the widget? Why is that legal?

Comment: @AmaniKilumanga what would be *illegal* about it?

Comment: Maybe perusing [opensource.SE](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/) would be useful. Maybe not.

Comment: Let's continue this discussion in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46625/cc-content-in-mit)...